# Reading list about the organisation of education in colleges in America

Tags: reference-request, curriculum

I have been chosen by my university (where I am a professor in science) to be part of a task force determining the undergraduate general education requirements. To be a better informed committee member, I am trying to understand the general situation at colleges in the country (the US) and the debates that have concerned this kind of questions. (To circumscribe a little the question, let us say that by "college" below I mean the top (e.g. top 100) liberal arts college and the top 100 colleges integrated in a university (Harvard college, etc.))

More specifically, I am trying to find good books that

1) describe the different types of policy that the colleges have.

For example:

a.-- Some colleges ask students to choose a *major* and a *minor*, other two equal *concentrations*. Are there colleges that require nothing of that sort? Which college do what? How many?

b.-- Some colleges force students to take classes in a variety of fields (science, humanity, arts, etc.). How widespread is that? What form does these requirements take?

c.-- Some colleges strongly encourage or force students to take a large number of courses where they would read about the "great books" of the Western Culture. See for examples the "core curriculum" at Columbia and Chicago. Other don't have that requirement, and some on the contrary require students to take a minimum number of courses directly concerning non-Western Cultures. Again, I'd like to know examples, and statistics.

d.-- Some colleges require student to know or learn at least one foreign language. How general is that? Are there schools that require two foreign languages? or one ancient language (like ancient Greek, Latin, Biblical Hebrew, Old Arabic, Hittite, Sanskrit, etc.)?

Etc.

2) Either neutrally explain or take a side with detailed arguments in the vigorous debates that have taken places in the academic community and beyond about those issues. (For example, my haphazard research with google led me to *The Closing of the American Mind*, which takes a vigorous position in factor of the first option in 1c above)

I am very thankful for any suggestion of readings on those subjects.

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Answer (score 2):

There should be a number of articles in the [*Chronicle of Higher Education*](http://chronicle.com) on such topics.  If you are a subscriber (or probably if your library is a subscriber?) you can search by keyword on their web site.

Answer (score 1):

The American Association of Colleges and Universities has recently published a survey of chief academic officers on recent trends in general education.  The survey and some related resources are at:

https://www.aacu.org/resources/general-education/publications